# keras categorical CNN prediction always output [[ 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]] No probability for other classes?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, cnn, probability

```
print(model.predict(image))
print(model.predict_proba(image))
print(model.predict_classes(image))
```

Using the above different predict methods I always get predictions like

> [[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]

but I want the probabilities of each classes something like this

> [[ 0.8  0.05  0.05  0.1]]

This is the model

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same',activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', ),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```

Compiled as

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001,momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer =sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Not sure if this has any effects, but this is how I loaded the data

> train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
>       rescale=1./255,
>   )
>
> train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(folder+'apex/train',
>                                                       target_size=(200, 400),
>                                                       batch_size=batch_size,
>                                                       class_mode='categorical')

Comment: How many instances do you have in training set? How many output classes are there?

Comment: @JahKnows there are 8 output classes, as for training instances :  'acuminate' 1382, 'apiculate'   238, 'obtuse'   260, 'acute'   1216, 'mucronate'   240, 'round'   248, 'bilobed'   124, 'emarginate'   106